# Cannot insert a new row to the database SQLite iPhone

Tags: ios, sqlite

I can not insert a new row to the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)InsertRecords{
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3 *cruddb;

    const char *sql = "Insert into AllDictionary(id, DeleteFlag, TitleBD, Description, PathToDB, ImageURL) VALUES('565','asasf2','asfas2ff','fggaga2hah','b2bb','aa2aa')";
    NSString *cruddatabase = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainDb.sqlite"];

    if(!(sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &cruddb)==SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));
    }
    if (sqlite3_prepare(cruddb, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));
    } else {
        sqlite3_step(stmt);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(cruddb);
}
```

Comment: what is the error ? Is there anything on the console ?

Comment: You have put the `id` value (`'565'`) in single quotes?  Is the `id` field a numeric field or a text/character field?

Comment: Check if result of `sqlite3_step() == SQLITE_DONE` and if not, examine `sqlite3_errmsg()`. It will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: no error.  'id' type is 'int'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Id type is int.
So the problem is with the query,

```
const char *sql = "Insert into AllDictionary(id, DeleteFlag, TitleBD, Description, PathToDB, ImageURL) VALUES('565','asasf2','asfas2ff','fggaga2hah','b2bb','aa2aa')";
```

Don't use quotes for integer values it's for string values.
change the query to:

```
const char *sql = "Insert into AllDictionary(id, DeleteFlag, TitleBD, Description, PathToDB, ImageURL) VALUES(565,'asasf2','asfas2ff','fggaga2hah','b2bb','aa2aa')";
```

And there are alot of mistakes in your method, like the prepare statement will always executed if the db is not opened. Finalize statement will work always with or without executing the prepare statement.
so re-write it like:

```
-(void)InsertRecords
{
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *cruddatabase = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainDb.sqlite"];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3 *cruddb;

    const char *sql = "Insert into AllDictionary(id, DeleteFlag, TitleBD, Description, PathToDB, ImageURL) VALUES(565,'asasf2','asfas2ff','fggaga2hah','b2bb','aa2aa')";

    if((sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &cruddb)==SQLITE_OK))
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare(cruddb, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_step(stmt);
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));
        }
        sqlite3_close(cruddb);
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));
    }
}
```

Comment: I re-wrote this method but not insert new row and no error! Maybe I'm calling the method wrong?'- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CrudOp *dbCrud = [[CrudOp alloc] init];    
    [dbCrud CopyDbToDocumentsFolder];
    [dbCrud InsertRecords];
    [dbCrud dictionaryList];
    self.thedictionaries=dbCrud.thedict;
    [super viewDidLoad];}'

Comment: dictionarylist this is method with sqlQuery select * from AllDictionary and it's work!                                 thedictionaries this is NSMutableArray in my class what inherited from UIViewController.            dbCrud.thedict this is NSMutableArray from CrudOp class and this array fills method dictionaryList.